# DataTable is not getting updated after reordering rows....(row-order)

Tags: javascript, html, datatable

I have something like this for table....

```
$("#objectPriorityTable").DataTable({
"ajax" : {
    url : "data/objectPriorityData.json",
    'async': 'false',
    dataSrc : function(json){
        var data = json;
        return data;
    },
    complete : function(jqXHR, textStatus){
        console.log(jqXHR);   
    },
    dataType : "json",
    columns : [
        { "data": "locatorType","defaultContent": ""},
        { "data": "locatorInfo","defaultContent": "" }
    ],
    columnDefs : [
        {
            "className": "dt-center", "targets": [3]
        },
        {
            width : "50%",
            "targets": 0
        },
        {
            "targets": 1,
            width : "50%", 
        },
        {
            orderable: true, className: 'reorder', targets: 0
        },
        {
            orderable: false, targets: '_all'
        }
    ],
    rowReorder: {
        update: false
    }
});
}
```

But when i reorder rows by dragging after when i drop the row the display get updated but
when I use this to get data it doesn't provide me updated data but the old data

```
table2 = $("#objectPriorityTable").dataTable();
table2.fnGetData();
```

How can I updated background structure of data. I mean the cache data of datatable...?
I have tried using draw() in "row-reorder" function callback...but it also updates the table to previous state i.e. state before reordering...